# How to monitor all network traffic from a specific process in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, networking, strace

I want to monitor and log all traffic that a specific process produces.

I know about `tcpdump`, but it seems it doesn't support filtering by process (pid/path, or at least user).

It there any other way to log all traffic from a process? Ideally I should be able to filter ports as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `strace` command:

```bash
strace -o /tmp/network.out -e trace=network -fp <PID>
```

Answer (score 0):

strace -f -s10000 -yy -xx -ttt -T -p *pid* | py_strace2pcap.py pcap.file

use tool from https://github.com/comboshreddies/py-strace2pcap

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35758003)